# What causes the creation of such a large number of Galera cache files?

Tags: mysql, cache, galera, xtradb-cluster

I manage a Percona XtraDB 3-node cluster. Recently the MySQL datadir of one of the nodes (not the one from which the cluster has been bootstrapped) started being filled up with `gcache.page.00nnnn` files. This is not happening in the other two nodes.

What causes the creation of such a large number of Galera cache files?

I stopped the daemon, wiped out the datadir and forced a SST on the node, but that's not really a solution -- I want to find the cause for this behaviour.

Comment: There seems to be (reported as fixed in 3.9) bug with Galera not deleting old files https://github.com/codership/galera/issues/229